# How do I get all GitHub secrets into env variables for Actions to access (powershell in my case)?

Tags: github, environment-variables, github-actions, github-secret

I read some similar posts but none seem to answer this question.  I can set individual GitHub secrets into environment variables in an Action if I know the name of the secret:
env:
PW_ID0007: "${{secrets.PW_ID0007}}"
How can I expose all secrets as environment variables without knowing their names (either in bulk or some way to iterate through them and set them individually?)

Answer (score 14):

There is a way to do that. Please check [here](https://github.community/t/exporting-all-secrets-in-a-workflow-action/122365/7)

```yaml
- name: view the secrets context
  shell: bash
  run: echo "$SECRETS_CONTEXT"
  env:
    SECRETS_CONTEXT: ${{ toJson(secrets) }}
```

In that way you will expose all secrets without knowing names:

[image]

And know what you need is go through this json using for instance jq and set them as env variable suing following syntax:

```
 echo "variable_name=variable_value" >> $GITHUB_ENV
```

Comment: Thanks,  This steered me in the right direction.  I was unaware of the GitHub toJson function you mention but found it documented here.

Comment: I was unaware of the GitHub toJson function you mention but found it documented here.
[link](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/context-and-expression-syntax-for-github-actions#tojson)

Adding this exposed all secrets in one JSON environment variable. 
`env: 
  SECRETS_CONTEXT: "${{ toJson(secrets) }}"`
I am using Powershell so I did not need jq. Within a Powershell script I can read and parse this with normal commands:
`$secrets = ($env:SECRETS_CONTEXT | ConvertFrom-Json -AsHashtable )`

Answer (score 9):

I created an action exactly for that - takes all the secrets and exports them to environment variables.

An example would be:

```
- run: echo "Value of MY_SECRET1: $MY_SECRET1"
  env:
    MY_SECRET1: ${{ secrets.MY_SECRET1 }}
    MY_SECRET2: ${{ secrets.MY_SECRET2 }}
    MY_SECRET3: ${{ secrets.MY_SECRET3 }}
    MY_SECRET4: ${{ secrets.MY_SECRET4 }}
    MY_SECRET5: ${{ secrets.MY_SECRET5 }}
    MY_SECRET6: ${{ secrets.MY_SECRET6 }}
    ...
```

You could convert it to:

```
- uses: oNaiPs/secrets-to-env-action@v1
  with:
    secrets: ${{ toJSON(secrets) }}
- run: echo "Value of MY_SECRET1: $MY_SECRET1"
```

Link to the action, which contains more documentation about configuration: https://github.com/oNaiPs/secrets-to-env-action

Answer (score 5):

I came up with a simple solution, which also works for multiline strings. Here is the corresponding GitHub action step:

```yaml
- name: Expose github environment as shell variables
  env:
    SECRETS_CONTEXT: ${{ toJson(secrets) }}
    VARS_CONTEXT: ${{ toJson(vars) }}
  run: |
    # https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#setting-an-environment-variable
    # https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#multiline-strings
    EOF=$(dd if=/dev/urandom bs=15 count=1 status=none | base64)
    to_envs() { jq -r "to_entries[] | \"\(.key)<<$EOF\n\(.value)\n$EOF\n\""; }
    echo "$VARS_CONTEXT" | to_envs >> $GITHUB_ENV
    echo "$SECRETS_CONTEXT" | to_envs >> $GITHUB_ENV
```

`jq` takes every key-value pair of the json and produces an env-command of the following form:

```
{name}<<{delimiter}
{value}
{delimiter}
```

For security reasons, the delemiter `$EOF` is a random string.

Those env-commands are then appended to `$GITHUB_ENV`, so that they are available in the next steps.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Just to add you can then use `envsubst < .env.example > .env` to populate your `.env.example` file with those env variables and save it into `.env`

Comment: This is perfect! I'm needing a way to pass vars context to a specific step without the need to have to update the workflow everytime I add a new one. This solves the problem really well

Comment: If one of `secrets` or `vars` is empty, then `toJson` will return `null`, not empty key-value object.