# Passing All GitHub Environment Variables and Secrets in a GitHub Actions Workflow

Tags: github, github-actions

For a repository on GitHub, I have configured an [Environment](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/deployment/targeting-different-environments/using-environments-for-deployment) with variables and secrets defined. I'd like to be able to use the entire collection in a GitHub Action without needing to individually map each variable from the github environment to the runner environment.

Given a `dev` environment defining `TOKEN`, `FOO`, `BAR`, and `BAZ` and the following workflow:

```yaml
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    environment: dev
    steps:
      - name: Build
        env:
          TOKEN: ${{ secrets.TOKEN }}
          FOO: ${{ vars.FOO }}
          BAR: ${{ vars.BAR }}
          BAZ: ${{ vars.BAZ }}
```

Is there a clever way to use the settings in the underlying sub-process environment without listing each variable (token, foo, bar, baz) explicitly?

Comment: One possible solution could be to define a single Github environment variable that is the contents of a .env file. So FOO, BAR, and BAZ would all be defined in `env.ENV_FILE_CONTENT` which would be dumped to a file and read by the underlying process.

Answer (score 1):

I have gotten this to work by first setting the vars context JSON to an environment variable, then using `jq` to process that JSON into `KEY=VALUE` format, and appending that to my `$GITHUB_ENV` file.

```yaml
jobs:
  Deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    environment:
      name: My Environment
    env:
      # this will take the entire vars context configured in the repository > environments
      # setting and convert it to JSON so we can automatically assign all the values to the
      # runner's environment
      VARS_CONTEXT: ${{ toJson(vars) }}
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Set up Node.js
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version-file: .nvmrc
          cache: npm
      - name: Set env vars from vars context JSON
        run: |
          # Pipe the JSON string into jq
          echo "$VARS_CONTEXT" | 
          # Convert JSON object into an array of key-value pairs
          jq -r 'to_entries | 
          # Map over each key-value pair
          .[] | 
          # Format each pair as "KEY=VALUE" and append it all to the environment file
          "\(.key)=\(.value)"' >> $GITHUB_ENV
      - name: Check env
        run: printenv
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that such a feature is too difficult for GitHub to implement.
[How do I get all GitHub secrets into env variables for Actions to access (powershell in my case)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68008181/how-do-i-get-all-github-secrets-into-env-variables-for-actions-to-access-powers)

The answer is, you cannot. The best you can do is export every env variable as a JSON, and then read / parse the whole env variable yourself, which is still bad.

```
- name: view the secrets context
  shell: bash
  run: echo "$SECRETS_CONTEXT"
  env:
    SECRETS_CONTEXT: ${{ toJson(secrets) }}
```